# regex find links

Tags: regex

Is it possible to split the following links.
I can select a link but not when they are paste right next to each other.

Thanx

Example: (I want to select these 3 links separately)
http://www.fileserve.com/file/7kXswvM/part1.rarhttp://www.fileserve.com/file/r4F3Gmh/part2.rarhttp://www.fileserve.com/file/r4F3Gmh/part3.rar

Comment: what environment do you want? C#, perl, a text editor?

Comment: So much for the `regex` tag’s advice to use a language or tool tag if you want to restrict answers to only one particular language or tool. Did I not phrase it strongly enough, or is that the neos just never look at the Excerpt of a particular tag?  Maybe SO should be changed to show a poster a tag’s Excerpt when people include a tag?

Comment: @tchrist: [People don't read.](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/uibook/chapters/fog0000000062.html) Joel says so himself.

Comment: To be fair, it is almost impossible for a new user to find the tag FAQ or wiki, specially before posting the question.

Answer (score 3):

You could split at `http://` and re-prepend that to every link (assuming it's all http only).

Answer (score 1):

```
http://(?:(?!http://).)*
```

will match a string that starts with `http://` up until either the next occurrence of `http://` or the end of the string.

```
>>> re.findall(r'http://(?:(?!http://).)*', 'http://www.fileserve.com/file/7kXswvM/part1.rarhttp://www.fileserve.com/file/r4F3Gmh/part2.rarhttp://www.fileserve.com/file/r4F3Gmh/part3.rar')
['http://www.fileserve.com/file/7kXswvM/part1.rar', 
'http://www.fileserve.com/file/r4F3Gmh/part2.rar', 
'http://www.fileserve.com/file/r4F3Gmh/part3.rar']
```

This will of course not quite work if anything other than a link follows in the input. As an alternative, the following regex will match until the next `http://` or until the next space (or end of string):

```
http://(?:(?!http://|\s).)*
```

Answer (score 0):

Match `http://`-s and split. According to the [spec](http://www.w3.org/Addressing/URL/url-spec.txt) it cannot appear in another parts of the URL.

Answer (score 0):

```
s/(?<=.)(?=http:)/\n/g;
```